# How to set Content-Disposition with AWS PHP SDK v2 and CopyObject?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I'm using the [AWS PHP SDK v2.x](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/) to copy objects between S3 buckets using the following code:

```
<?php
try {
    self::$aws->copyObject(array(
        'Bucket'     => $target_bucket,
        'Key'        => $target_key,
        'CopySource' => $source_bucket . '/' . $source_key,
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment',
        //'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . basename($target_key) . '"'
        //'ContentDisposition' => 'attachment'
        //'ContentDisposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . basename($target_key) . '"'
    ));
} catch (Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception $e) {
    echo 'error';
}
```

The file is copied to the S3 bucket without any errors, but I'm unable to set the the `Content-Disposition` in order to force the browser to download the file rather than stream it. I've tried a few options (commented out above) but nothing seem to work.

I've even attempted to pass the value in the `Metadata` array even though the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html) says otherwise but the [AWS Console](http://aws.console.com) lists the `Content-Disposition` under the Metadata section.

If I manually change the `Content-Disposition` in the [AWS Console](http://aws.console.com) then the browser downloads the file as expected.

So, how can I pass the value to the S3 object correctly? *Can* I pass it at all using the `CopyObject()` method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `CopyObject` operation is tricky, IMO. I think the missing piece of the puzzle for you is the `MetadataDirective` parameter. Try the following:

```
$s3Client->copyObject(array(
    'Bucket'     => $target_bucket,
    'Key'        => $target_key,
    'CopySource' => $source_bucket . '/' . $source_key,
    'ContentDisposition' => 'attachment; filename="'.basename($target_key).'"',
    'MetadataDirective'  => 'REPLACE',
));
```

*Note: The code is in this post is also licensed under version 2.0 of the Apache License.*

Comment: The `ContentDisposition` only needs the "attachment" value specified for it to work, but the `MetadataDirective` was the missing piece of information.

Comment: This does a good job of setting ContentDisposition, but unfortunately destroys Content-type.  What's the best way to do this while preserving content-type?

Comment: @ChadE.: You could do a head request first and grab the existing Content-Type, Metadata, or whatever other information you need from the existing file and include it/them in your copyObject args. I'm not sure if there is an easier way to accomplish what you need.